# Add data behind string based on data in other column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, replace, sql-update

I have the following challenge which I can't solve at the moment:

I have a column (LongTextfield1) in, let's say, table 'Data' that contains HTML data. Each row in table 'Data' is basically a document with text and pictures. In several occassions multiple pictures are included in the same column (LongTextfield1). In case of a picture, the following code will be shown that refers to the picture:

\Download.aspx?DocumentID={SomeGUID}

To make it a bit more challenging, this piece of code can be included in the same column multiple times, depending on how much pictures are included in the HTML (document). All pictures have their own GUID. So far, so good. This is already present in the column.

In the application that I would like to show these pictures I also need a 'RecordID'. This is a unique ID per picture. So, outcome should be:

\Download.aspx?DocumentID={SomeGUID}&Recorid=SomeID

I have a table 'DocumentData' that contains the unique GUID (DocumentID) and RecordID for each picture. So, I know which RecordID belongs to each GUID.

I need a stored procedure (or other automatic mechanism) that adds the RecordID behind the corresponding GUID. I have tried to use REPLACE '{SomeGUID}' for {SomeGUID}&RecorID=SomeID' but that didn't work. Below is the stored procedure, that is fed with data from the 'DocumentData' table. It keeps on replacing the same string with every possible GUID+RecordID combination: (DocumentID={SomeGUID}&RecordID=1{SomeGUID2}&RecordID2.. etc. and that's not what I want. @DocumentID and @Origin (RecorID) in the stored procedure refer to the 'DocumentData' table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Replace_Picture2] (
@DocumentID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@Origin varchar(100)
) AS

BEGIN

update
data
set longtextfield1 = REPLACE(CAST(LongTextField1 AS VARCHAR(max)), ltrim(cast(@DocumentID as varchar(100))) + '}', ltrim(cast(@DocumentID as varchar(100))) + '}' + '&RecordID=' + @Origin + '"')
where 1=1
and pageid = 1
and groupid = 2
and subgroupid = 8

END

GO
```

How can I achieve to add the RecordID behind the DocumentID, based on the combinations present in table 'DocumentData'? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by replacing ‘@DocumentID’ + ‘}”’ (notice the ‘}”’ instead of ‘}’. This prevents the stored procedure to keep on replacing and replacing..